# why isnt my second view loading after transition?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I have two views, the initial one that works fine, and a second one that I am trying to display after I transition to it from a button on the first view.

However, when I click the button, the transition happens and the screen goes blank.

Below is the `viewDidLoad` inside of the `UIViewController` class for the second view.

Also when it hits the

```
let sKView = view as! SKVIEW
```

line it spits out

> Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x10a313eb0) to 'SKView' (0x1094d5718).
>   (lldb)

How do I get it to display the view?

```
class PlayViewController: UIViewController {

    var scene2: PlayScene!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    scene2 = PlayScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    scene2.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    skView.presentScene(scene2)
}
```

first class

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

the second scene

```
import SpriteKit

class PlayScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
        myLabel.text = "SCENE 2!";
        myLabel.fontSize = 65;
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

            sprite.xScale = 0.5
            sprite.yScale = 0.5
            sprite.position = location

            let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)

            sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

            self.addChild(sprite)
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: You get the error for the reason stated. The view controller's view isn't an `SKView`. It's a plain old `UIView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your view controllers view is your everyday run of the mill UIView instead of an SKView. Assuming you are using a storyboard click on the view controller and then click on the view and change the class to SKView instead of UIView.

[image]

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: thanks allot for your easy to understand solution, however in the class dropdown there is no option for an SKView.  Do I need to do something else?

Comment: Yeah that is an odd bug with Xcode if you just type it in it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to archive, you can try change your super class from `UIViewController` to `SpriteViewController` or you can create a new `SKView` and append to your view.

You cannot downcast a UIView to a SKView as a SKView inherit from UIView as you can see in the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html)

```
Inherits From
  NSObject
    UIResponder
      UIView
        SKView
```

Comment: I would just like to point out that I am new to this, I just started teaching myself about two weeks ago,    anyways, I have nearly an Identicle set up in my first ViewController and it works fine, all im trying to do is reset the scene to a different SKScene class that I created

Comment: Can you also post your first class? So we can try to see what is happening

Comment: Its the standard that comes with a new sprite kit game just posted it above